# How do you migrate YUM packages to new server

Tags: yum, package-management

I moved to a new server and I want to move all the packages I installed through YUM on the old server to the new one.  Also I will need to move the repositories with this.  How can I do that? I looked online and I'm not finding this anywhere.

Comment: Why not just install them? just issue `yum install` on new server (same as you did on old server, one thing you may want to carry over is your `/etc/yum.repos.d`.

Comment: i was about to ask about keys but the post below answered it.

Comment: keys are part of repo and they're public, they'd get imported to your system as soon as you try to install package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start such a script by copying the contents of `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/` to the new system and install the packages listed when running `yum list installed` on the original system.

Comment: This assumes they're the same version of the same distribution.

Comment: worked great, thank you.  Saved me a lot of frustration.  Helped more than you know.  thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's true @GregL.   Glad I could help, learning-it.